# Rails routing: add (shallow) concern to root

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my routes.rb, I defined a concern like below:

```
concern :namespaceable do
  resources :comments do
    resources :replies
  ...
```

Now, I can add this concern to any resources:

```
resources :groups, concerns: :namespaceable, shallow: true
```

But how can I add this concern **shallowly** to the root, so that I can have following routes

- /comments
- /comments/{comment_id}
- /comments/{comment_id}/replies
- /replies/{reply_id}

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write `concerns: :namespaceable` in the main file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  concern :namespaceable do
    resources :comments do
    resources :replies
    ...
  end

  concerns :namespaceable # Will add to root namespace
end
```